# Summing the elements of a list recursively

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, divide-and-conquer

```
def sum(L):
    if len(L) == 1:
        return L[0]
    i = sum (len (L) // 2)
    if  len(L) > 1:
        return i + i

L=[2,4]

print (sum(L))
```

when i try to run it there is a TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len().

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: expected result is the summatory of the elements of the list in this example it has to be 6

Comment: You can't accept more than one answer. Did you read all the answers to determine what was most helpful for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you were aiming for was to write a recursive `sum` function that continuously splits the list into smaller chunks. So basically what you need to do is compute the index of the midpoint, then use list slicing to pass the first sublist and second sublist recursively back into the function, until hitting your base case(s) of `0` or `1` elements remaining.

```
def add(values):
    if len(values) == 0:
        return 0
    elif len(values) == 1:
        return values[0]
    mid = len(values)//2
    return add(values[:mid]) + add(values[mid:])

>>> add([1,2,3,4,5])
15
```

Comment: Thank you! i will try to be more clear the next time. Now it works

Answer (score 3):

In `sum (len (L) // 2)`, you're passing an integer (the result of `len(L) // 2`) as the `L` argument to your `sum()` function.  (Please don't give functions the same name as built-in functions.)  The recursively-called `sum()` then tries to evaluate `len(L) == 1` on this integer, but integers don't support `len()`, and so you get the error message in question.  What exactly are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't name your function `sum`, it shadows the builtin function
2. Implement your function so as to clearly define a base case and a recursive case.

   For the base case, when the length is 1, return that element. You've got this right.
   For the recursive case, split your list into half and recursively compute the sum for each half.

```
def sum_recursive(L):
    if len(L) == 1:
        return L[0]

    idx = len(L) // 2
    return sum_recursive(L[:idx]) + sum_recursive(L[idx:])
```

`sum_recursive` must always receive a list and return an integer.

Some dry runs:

```
In [5]: sum_recursive([1, 2, 4, 8])
Out[5]: 15

In [6]: sum_recursive([2, 4])
Out[6]: 6
```

---

Keep in mind that this won't be able to handle empty lists as input. If you want to account for that as well, change your base case to:

```
def sum_recursive(L):
    if len(L) <= 1:
        return sum(L)
    ...
```

We're making use of the builtin `sum` function here which handles empty lists gracefully by returning 0. For single-element lists, the first element is returned (this is also why it is important you don't shadow these utility functions).

If you don't want to use `sum` there, you'll need to split your base case into two parts:

```
def sum_recursive(L):
    if len(L) == 0:
        return 0
    elif len(L) == 1:
        return L[0]
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code

> i = sum (len (L) // 2)

line is throwing an error because in recursion after the first call of sum() you are passing an integer not list

```
def sum(L):
    if len(L) == 0:
        return 0
    elif len(L) == 1:
        return L[0]
    else:
        index = len(L)-1
        return L[index] + sum(L[0:index])

L=[2,4]

print (sum(L))
```